# update records in mysqli using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

i try to update records in mysqli database using prepared statement, but it doesn't work for me.
please check my code.
Thank you.

```
$editPostID = $_POST['postID'];
$newHeader = $_POST['newHeader'];
$newSubHeader = $_POST['newPostSubHeader'];
$newBody = $_POST['postBodyE'];
$oldCat = $_POST['oldCategory'];
$newCat = $_POST['newCategory'];

$sql = "UPDATE database.posts
SET postHeader=?, postSubHeader=?, postBody=?, category=?
WHERE ID=?";


$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($myConn);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $newHeader, $newSubHeader, $newBody, 
$newCat, $editPostID);

 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: "_it doesn't work for me_" :( What does that even mean?

Comment: You have to check the output of `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` and `mysqli_stmt_execute()` to see where your program fails.

Answer (score 0):

solved, i found the mistake.
when binding the parameters and declaring the variables types, for the ID has to be declare letter D(data type), s(string type)(at least i think this is it)
`

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssd", $newHeader, $newSubHeader, $newBody, 
$newCat, $editPostID);
```